# gk 3 with GR33 module in my electric guitar

Tags: guitar

i have a electric guitar where i need to connect sustain gear is it possible to connect in my guitar.... i have GK2 and  GR 33 maodule.... where iam finding difficult in playing glide notes.. thought of buying GK3 midi pickup...  will GK3 midi pickup works with GR33 module'

Comment: If you don’t need a dedicated pedal on stage and ”sounds like MIDI” sounds, ditch the GK and GR-33, they are a clunky complicated last decade system. There’s a program/app called MIDI Guitar 2, which works better and doesn’t need a GK hex pickup. Works polyphonically from regular guitar input, tracks fast and clear. I have a GR-33 and it’s useless now.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - how does MIDI guitar-2 work in live gig situations?

Comment: @Tim you need to have a laptop, rack PC, iPad or something. Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhSYE_51vBo

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - had a horrible feeling that's the case! I have enough paraphernalia to set up already, certainly don't want the bother of a computer of any sort. Have loads of MIDI stuff that I use with keys, but want to use them with guitar or bass. Guess I need to wait while technology plods on.

Answer (score 1):

If you do what I did - google GR-33 - within 10 seconds the answer was there.

It will have sustain and a myriad of other effects too, but I think as a start point you need to try getting your playing more legato and smooth by yourself. Rather than relying on a crutch for your playing.

Try playing more slowly, and eliminate gaps between notes. Develop your vibrato, as this helps prolong notes.

A compressor pedal will help sustain in a less invasive (to your pocket) way. Also remember that the Roland pup will have to be fitted in a more or less permanent way, making the guitar less easy to sell eventually.